# Independent variables still independent with additional information?

Tags: probability

A simple question: Assume that two random variables $A$ and $B$ are independent, and so $E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$. If we take into account some additional information denoted by the information set $X$, does it follow that $E[AB | X]=E[A | X]E[B | X]$ regardless of what this information set $X$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if $A$ and $B$ are dice rolls and $X$ implies information about the sum it will no longer be the case that they are independent.

For example with two d2's we have $E[AB] = 9/4$ (and $E[A]=E[B] = 3/2$), but given the sum being $3$ we will have $E[AB|X] = (1\cdot2 + 2\cdot1)/2 = 2$ and $E[A|X] = E[B|X]= (1+2)/2 = 3/2$ so the equality doesn't hold.